# Failing to initialize Public key object using CX509PublicKey::InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo

Tags: c#, rsa, public-key, x509certificate2

I am trying to initialize the public key object using the existing public key that I read from the available cert but it is failing with the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: CertEnroll::CX509PublicKey::InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo: **Bad Data. 0x80090005 (-2146893819 NTE_BAD_DATA)**

From the exception, it is understandable that it is trying to point that the correct format is not supplied but I fail to understand what I am missing here. The code looks as simple as it could be,

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(TestConstants.TestCertPath));
pubStr = Convert.ToBase64String(cert.GetPublicKey());
publicKey.InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo(pubStr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY);
```

Answer (score 0):

IX509PublicKey::InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo expects an outer `PublicKey` structure, which includes key algorithm, parameters and public key itself (for RSA, it is both, modulus and public exponent):

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
  algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
  subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The `X509Certificate2.GetPublicKey()` method returns only last component (content of `subjectPublicKey` component inside BIT_STRING), without key algorithm identifier and algorithm parameters (curve ID for EC keys).

Unfortunately, .NET doesn't provide native access to `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. You may need to use 3rd party libraries to get this piece of data or manually parse the certificate using ASN.1 parsers to get this info. Starting with .NET 5, there is [AsnDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asndecoder?view=net-6.0) you can use for manual certificate parsing.

Comment: will this .net library work, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-6.0

Comment: Yes, but that's not convertible to `IX509PublicKey` COM interface if you need it. If not, you have an XY problem.

Comment: If I have to break the problem, I would say, I only need Exponent and Modulus as base64 encoded string. I can just append the Algo info to it. but I am unable to parse the Public key info as modules and exponent part.

Comment: RSACryptoServiceProvider key = cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            RSAParameters parameters = key.ExportParameters(false);
            string exponent =  parameters.Exponent.ToString();
            string modulus = parameters.Modulus.ToString();

Comment: Then you had an XY problem.